# Resize dialog box according to iframe content

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, dialog

Hi guys I have been wracking my head with this for 2 days.

Cant seem to come up with a solution

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMJCw/)

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div/>', {'class':'myDlgClass', 'id':'link-'+($(this).index()+1)})
        .html($('<iframe/>', {
            'src' : $(this).attr('href'),
            'style' :'width:100%; height:100%;border:none;'
        })).appendTo('body')
        .dialog({
        'title' : $(this).text(),
        width : 450,
        height : 350,
            buttons: [ { 
                    text: "Close",
                    click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } 
                } ]
        });
    });
});
```

The iframe gets autoresized to 100%, however the dialog box wont auto resize. i dont want page scrollers. have tried alot of sequences on auto resizing dialogs but nothing works.

I have internal php forms that I link in with href, all forms will be different and will require the dialog box to resize according to the iframe size.
I do have css so formating the user forms is not a problem they are all in DIV

problem is the dialog box scroller.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NMJCw/2/

```
resize: function (event, ui) {
   var heightDifference = 50;
   var widthDifference = 50;
   $('iframe').height($(this).height() - heightDifference);
   $('iframe').width($(this).width() - widthDifference);
},
```

With the resize event of the dialog box, you can set the iframes width and height. I also added two vars which are the dimension differences between the iframe and the dialog box - you need to calculate the right values and change them.

Also while resizing **sometimes** theres a weird scrollbar. Maybe you can inspect it and set some overflow:hidden (i havent found the right element to set the overflow).

Comment: That isnt helping the cause. I have updated the problem in a little detail please check jfiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/NMJCw/3/

Comment: hmm. what i can say is that there are enough methods to change either the dialog box and iframe dimension. like the try in my answer above. to make it clear after reading your question now a third time, i dont get your problem. except the strange scrollbar while resizing, your problem seems not to occur in the fiddle?